# How to get an API get request's query parameter using Playwright-Java

Tags: playwright, browser-automation, playwright-java

Context:
Trying to intercept and Replace a browser get request's query string parameters using playwright Java.

I am able to print the URL of the get request along with the query string parameters using `page.onRequest`.

Issue:

Please help me find a method in the request object that could retrieve the query string parameters in the payload section or any other way to  intercept and Replace a browser get request's query string parameters.

PFB Playwrights available methods in the request object:

[image: available request methods]

PFB the Network tab log of the fired get request

[image]